# How to use pandas datafames in weka wrapper instead of arff files?

Tags: python, weka

I am new to this weka wrapper and trying to apply the attribute selection algorithm on my panda's data frame `bowDataFrame`. Please help.
`

```
jvm.start(packages=True)
search = ASSearch(classname="weka.attributeSelection.BestFirst", options=["-D", "1", "-N", "5"])
evaluator = ASEvaluation(classname="weka.attributeSelection.CfsSubsetEval", options=["-P", "1", "-E", "1"])
print("We are here")
attsel = AttributeSelection()
attsel.search(search)
attsel.evaluator(evaluator)
attsel.select_attributes(bowDataFrame)`
```